# How to create embeddedings for a column that is a list of categorical values

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow

I am having some trouble deciding how to create embeddings for a categorical feature for my DNN model. The feature consists of a non fixed set of tags.

The feature is like:

```
column = [['Adventure','Animation','Comedy'],
          ['Adventure','Comedy'],
          ['Adventure','Children','Comedy']
```

I would like to do this with `tensorflow` so I know the [tf.feature_column](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column) module should work, I just don't know which version to use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the categories to embeddings using tf.feature_column the best option is [tf.feature_column.embedding_column](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/embedding_column).